# Computing the union and intersection of two unsorted arrays in O(mlogn) time

Tags: algorithm, set, time-complexity, theory, array-algorithms

Okay, so I need to devise the following algorithm (NO CODE NEEDED, just steps):

Given two sets `A` and `B` with length `m` and `n` respectively where the numbers in each set are distinct, unsorted, and `m<n`. Compute the intersection and union of the two sets without any duplicate values in either result. The algorithm should work in O(mlog(n)) time.

I'm having a really hard time figuring out an algorithm with such a time complexity. Initially, I wanted to concat the two unsorted arrays and then perform a merge sort on it and remove duplicates but that goes way over the alotted complexity.

Comment: This is impossible for plain unordered arrays. Imagine a single-item A being inserted into a large array B then you'll to at least examine every entry of B once in linear (`O(n)`) time. Of course for hash tabled stored _in_ arrays you could do it in `O(m+n)` time on average, would that be allowed?

Comment: hmmm, i'm not sure. I'll go to office hours with my professor tomorrow and see how she expects it to happen, because I agree that it seems fairly impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I missread the performance requirement. The solution is in `O(n log(m))` and not as required in `O(m log(n) )`.

The required runtime is imho not possible. The proof was sketched already in the comments. The basic idea is to go to the extrem case where `A` is the singleton set. Then the performance requirements boils down to check whether a given element is contained in a set `B` in runtime `O(log(|B|))`. This is to the best of my knowledge, however, only possible if `B` is sorted or there is some kind of indexing structure over `B`.

---

The `O(blog(m))` solution

As `m<n` you can sort `A` the result is `As`. Sorting `A` is `O(m log(m)) < O(m log(n) )`.

Finding an element in the sorted `As`  is in `O(log(m))`. So you just need to check each instance of `B` and figure whether it is contained in `As`.

resulting runtime (abusing notation) is 
`O(n log(n))+ m* O(log(n)) = O(n log(n))+ O(n* log(m))=O(n log(m))`

Comment: Close, but you're confusing your `m` and `n`. Sorting `A` is O(m log m), not O(n log n). Searching for an item in the sorted `A` is O(log m), which you do `n` times. So the result is `(m * log(m)) + (n * log(m))`. Also, the problem states that "the numbers in each set are distinct," so you don't have to worry about there being duplicates in `B`.

Comment: Thanks the array to be sorted should indeed be `B`

Comment: If `m < n`, then `n*log(n) > m*log(n)`